# Add new entry to an array in Python and remove the last entry

Tags: python, arrays

I want to add a new entry to an array and remove the last entry. I want to do this without using `pop` or `append` etc.

**Attempt**

```
def main():
    array = [1,2,3,4,5]
    array_len = len(array)
    new_val  = 9
    print(array)

    for i in range(0,array_len-1):
        temp = array[i]
        array[i] = array[i+1]
        array[i+1]= temp

    array[0] = new_val
    print(array)   

main()
```

The output gives `[9,3,4,5,1]` when the answer I want is `[9,1,2,3,4]`. Any tips on how I can correct the logic used would be great!

**Edit**

I should have been more clear. I want to do this using only logic and loops, without using built in python functions or array operations like array[:-1] etc..

Comment: Why not `[new_val] + array[:-1]`?

Comment: `array.insert( 0, val )` ?

Comment: "I want to do this without using pop or append etc"  **Why?** what is it with these arbitrary restrictions? Also, you should probably be using deque with a max length: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: @lenik yes but don't forget you need to remove last too

Comment: @AntonvBR he can figure out how to do it himself

Comment: Btw: please don't call it array when you mean a list ... since arrays are a thing in python as well (see: [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html)).

Comment: You might write `print array` inside the for loop to see what's going on through each iteration of the loop.  It might give you a little more insight than just seeing the wrong answer at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best Code !!!

Just modified your code to work

```
def main():
    array = [1,2,3,4,5]
    array_len = len(array)
    new_val  = 9
    print(array)

    temp = array[0]
    array[0] = new_val
    for i in range(0,array_len-1):
        temp1 = array[i+1]
        array[i+1] = temp
        temp = temp1

    print(array)   

main()
```

Comment: This works, but is much more complicated and verbose than the other solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
new_array = [9] + array[:-1]
```

Result:

```
[9, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`array[:-1]` means: take all items in `array` except the last one.

By adding this to a list containing only the number 9, you get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough with list literals and slices:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
new_val  = 9

# option 1: new object
array = [new_val] + array[:-1]

# option 2: mutate existing array by slice assingment
array[:] = [new_val] + array[:-1]
```